# Como hago un Trigger en Google App Script que se ejecute al recibir valores de otro libro de Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, trigger, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un script en un Sheet que al terminar su proceso envía un texto mediante .setValue() a otros libros diferentes de Sheet para que cada uno ejecute una función diferente. El problema es que en esos otros libros ningun activador inicia el proceso de ejecución, ya intente con OnEdit, OnChange y los activadores propios que tiene App Script (Al editase, Al producirse un cambio).

Al parecer estos activadores solo funcionan cuando haces algun cambio ó editas directamente en la hoja, no cuando recibes texto. Tambien intente poniendo un IMPORTRANGE y no se activa. No quiero tener el activador por tiempo ya que necesito que se ejecute al recibir la información.

NOTA: Los scrips funcionan correctamente al ejecutar manualmente y con los activadores de tiempo.

```
    function miFuncion(){ 
 const e = { source: 
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
  }       
  functionenviaCandidatos(e);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1pwO3RjQ7VnugweZPqjYuY14IF8t4W9QLtp4JtFyE_NY");
  var hojaOrigen = ss.getSheetByName("Data1"); var rangoOrigen = hojaOrigen.getRange(2,1,1000,8).getValues();
  var destino = SpreadsheetApp.openById("17qi7-Icn_5z3sRPybApQ3Nw5tIux5PUsiH7ps5NUoQk");  
 var hojaDestino = destino.getSheetByName("Candidatos");var ultimafila = hojaDestino.getLastRow()+1 destino.getActiveSheet().getRange(ultimafila, 1, 1000, 8).setValues(rangoOrigen);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

En Google Apps Script los triggers no pueden ser activados por eventos generados por otros triggers:

- edit (editar) sólo se activa cuando un usuarios hace una edición usando la interfaz de Google Sheets
- change (cambio) se activa cuando se realizan cambios a la hoja de cálculo excepto si esos cambios son realizados por Google Apps Script

Una opción es que tu script llame la función asociada al activador y si es necesario que es pase objeto con la estructura requerida. Por ejemplo

```
function miFuncion(){
  const e = {
    source: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  }
  functionDeActivador(e);
}
```

Comment: Hola Rubén gracias por tu respuesta, en tu ejemplo en lugar de  functionDeActivador(e); ¿en ese lugar ubicaria la funcion que yo hice (incluyendo la (e) ?

Comment: @JuanAlfredoMezaM Así es

Comment: Incluí mi codigo pero me marca un error, podrías darle un vistazo para ver en donde esta mi error ?

Comment: function miFuncion(){
  const e = {
    source: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  }
functionenviaCandidatos(e);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1pwO3RjQ7VnugweZPqjYuY14IF8t4W9QLtp4JtFyE_NY");
var hojaOrigen = ss.getSheetByName("Data1");
var rangoOrigen = hojaOrigen.getRange(2,1,1000,8).getValues();
var destino = SpreadsheetApp.openById("17qi7-Icn_5z3sRPybApQ3Nw5tIux5PUsiH7ps5NUoQk");
var hojaDestino = destino.getSheetByName("Candidatos");var ultimafila = hojaDestino.getLastRow()+1
destino.getActiveSheet().getRange(ultimafila, 1, 1000, 8).setValues(rangoOrigen);
}

Comment: @JuanAlfredoMezaM Agrega el código a la pregunta por favor.

Comment: listo agregué el ejemplo